# Add Image to UIAlertAction in UIAlertController

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller

I have seen a couple screen shots of a UIAlertControllers with an image on the left of the row but I do not seen it in the documentation. An example visual is [image: http://imgur.com/SISBvjB]
Here is the code that I have for my controller right now:

```
UIAlertController * view =   [UIAlertController
                                 alertControllerWithTitle:@"My Title"
                                 message:@"Select you Choice"
                                 preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
    UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction
                         actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                         style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                         handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                         {
                          }];
    [view addAction:ok];
    [self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: There is no API to customize the buttons of a `UIAlertController`. Whatever screenshots you have seen are not using `UIAlertController`.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the OP but I don't think he wants to customize the alert buttons but add an image to the alert.

Comment: This is what I am trying to create http://imgur.com/SISBvjB

Comment: @user1079052 you should accept JPs answer as the correct answer. It is definetly the best one on SO

Answer (score 123):

And that's how it's done:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "myImage")
var action = UIAlertAction(title: "title", style: .default, handler: nil)
action.setValue(image, forKey: "image")
alert.addAction(action)
```

the image property is not exposed, so there's no guarantee of this working in future releases, but works fine as of now

Comment: Thank you! Here is the objective C equivalent:                     UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
[bluetoothButton setValue:image forKey:@"image"];

Comment: Do you happen to know what is the key to set an image on the right side, essentially the accessory view?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a property for that. You would have to build a more hacky solution that recursively loops through all the alertController's view subviews, and then add an image subview to that. Again, could you mark my answer as correct if that worked for you

Comment: Thank you @JPHribovsek poor SO user. This answer should be accepted as the correct answer. All i can do is upvote

Comment: I tried it in Objective-c..it works but the image gets displayed on the left side. Any way of putting it in the middle of the button?

Comment: Apple won't reject it?

Comment: @Georg no, I don't see why

Comment: doesn't seem to work with xCode 6.3 - only blue squares in places of the icons

Comment: but the image tintcolor is changed, how can i set original image to it?

Comment: @PatelJigar change rendering mode to always original `action.setValue(image.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal), forKey: "image")`

Comment: How can you give forKey:@"image"? Is it inbuild? I changed the key but it  crashed.

Comment: works on iPhone, but on iPad if I set alertcontroller.view.tintcolor and add the image, the tintcolor is ignored.

Comment: @masgar see the comments above for Patel Jigar, @jaytrixz mentions `imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)`

Comment: the " forKey:'image' "... where do you even find documentation on this?

Comment: Only seeing a solid blue rectangle? This fix will help. `action.setValue(UIImage(named:"image")!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal), forKey: "image")` It's a shame Apple didn't provide a simple method to add in images, BUT... hate to rain on the parade, this method here would seem to really be non compliant with the guidelines. It essentially places an image into the alert view's button area and affects the sizing of other alertview buttons. Plus, is this accessibility compliant? These are just two considerations.

Comment: @JPHribovsek because this is using a non public api of an apple framework. that is pretty much a guarantee to get rejected

Comment: @DavidSeek nope, the API used here is `setValue:forKey:`, which is a public API; been used in the app store many times, no rejects

Answer (score 27):

```
UIAlertController * view=   [UIAlertController
                             alertControllerWithTitle:@"Staus ! "
                             message:@"Select your current status"
                             preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];


UIAlertAction* online = [UIAlertAction
                     actionWithTitle:@"Online"
                     style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                     handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                     {
                         //Do some thing here
                         [view dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                     }];
UIAlertAction* offline = [UIAlertAction
                         actionWithTitle:@"Offline"
                         style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                         handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                         {
                             [view dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                         }];
UIAlertAction* doNotDistrbe = [UIAlertAction
                         actionWithTitle:@"Do not disturb"
                         style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                         handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                         {
                             [view dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                         }];
UIAlertAction* away = [UIAlertAction
                               actionWithTitle:@"Do not disturb"
                               style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive
                               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                               {
                                   [view dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                               }];

[online setValue:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"online.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] forKey:@"image"];
[offline setValue:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"offline.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] forKey:@"image"];
[doNotDistrbe setValue:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"DND.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] forKey:@"image"];
[away setValue:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"away.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] forKey:@"image"];





[view addAction:online];
[view addAction:away];
[view addAction:offline];
[view addAction:doNotDistrbe];
[self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Hi,How could we add the image to left of the text. I have that requirement in my app.Thank You

Comment: @SMS Until Apple expose this as a public property it may not be as simple as "wanting to move the image". You could try subclassing UIAlertController and override the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and access the object via KVO like above `let image = self.valueForKey("image")` but that would give you the image. Long story short, it is probably very difficult to do it in such a way that apple won't reject your app. Easiest option is to create your own Alert Controller

Comment: That works  to add an image on the button (action) of the view. Not work to add image to message.

Comment: It's just what I needed. The only problem is that you use the image you use, although it has a lot of resolution, it always looks blurred in the menu. Does anyone else have this problem?

Answer (score 13):

You could add an image above the title label by subclassing `UIAlertController` and adding `\n` to the title string to make space for the `UIImageView`. You'd have to compute the layout based on the font size. For images in the `UIAlertAction` use `KVC` like so `self.setValue(image, forKey: "image")`. I would recommend to use an extension that checks for `responds(to:)`. [Here is sample implementation.](http://www.stringcode.co.uk/alertviewcontroller/)

[image]

Comment: Awesome, mate. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: This solution code does not make space for UIImageView above title string. See - [Inline Code Link](https://pastebin.com/QdcVkRZM), [Inline Image Link](https://ibb.co/ZY3LCtx).

Answer (score 11):

**For swift**

```
let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
let action = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Share", comment: ""), style: .default, handler: { _ in
        })
let image = UIImage(named: "Temp1")
action.setValue(image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), forKey: "image")
actionSheet.addAction(action)
actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Note: IMP Line **withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)**

Answer (score 9):

Try something like this:

```
UIAlertView* alert = [UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Test Alert" message: @"Alert With Custom View" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"NO" otherButtonTitles:@"YES", nil];

UIImage* imgMyImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
UIImageView* ivMyImageView = [UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, imgMyImage.size.width, imgMyImage.size.height)];
[ivMyImageView setImage:imgMyImage];

[alert setValue: ivMyImageView forKey:@"accessoryView"];
[alert show];
```

Tested this and it works for iOS 7.0

[image]

Comment: Than you for the help but I need an image on the left of a button in an action sheet. For example there is one on the call screen when you switch between your audio outputs of bluetooth, speaker and device, etc....

Comment: Is it safe to submit an app including this "hack" to the App Store? Won't it be rejected?

Comment: Not sure why you think this is a hack, it's all in the framework.

Comment: It doesn't work
Error message:
setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key accessoryView.

Comment: Are animated images supported?

Comment: I would think animated gifs are since UIImageView supports them. For other formats you would need to check the docs.

Comment: UIAlertView is depricated in iOS9, use UIAlertController instead!

Comment: Can you please post your answer for iOS 9 sir..?

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIAlertController 0x7fd6a8c57c70> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key accessoryView.'

Comment: Do you have any ideas for UIAlertController?

Comment: @PruitIgoe How to fix alertview width and Height.

Answer (score 1):

Swift Version:

```
actionBtn.setValue(UIImage.init(named: "completeDose"), forKey: "image")
```

Answer (score 0):

### swift code

let customActionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

```
    let firstButton = UIAlertAction(title: "First Button", style: .default, handler: { action in
        //click action
    })
    firstButton.setValue(UIColor.black, forKey: "titleTextColor")
    firstButton.setValue(UIColor.black, forKey: "imageTintColor")
    firstButton.setValue(NSNumber(value: true), forKey: "checked")
    
    let secondButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Second Button", style: .default, handler: { action in
        //click action
    })
    
    secondButton.setValue(UIColor.black, forKey: "titleTextColor")
    let cancelButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { action in
        //cancel
    })
    cancelButton.setValue(UIColor.black, forKey: "titleTextColor")
    
    customActionSheet.addAction(firstButton)
    customActionSheet.addAction(secondButton)
    customActionSheet.addAction(cancelButton)
    
    present(customActionSheet, animated: true)enter code here
```

Answer (score -1):

swift 3 extension , property and convenience init.

```
extension UIAlertAction{
    @NSManaged var image : UIImage?

    convenience init(title: String?, style: UIAlertActionStyle,image : UIImage?, handler: ((UIAlertAction) -> Swift.Void)? = nil ){
        self.init(title: title, style: style, handler: handler)
        self.image = image
    }
}
```

thanks to Shahar Stern for the inspiration

Comment: You should not use NSManaged for non NSManagedObjects classes. The fact that under the hood the UIAlertAction responded to setImage does not make this snippet bullet proof. If the "under the hood" implementation changes this code would cause crash.

Comment: Any use of undocumented api should be used with caution, And NSManager is the swift's dynamic (the one instead of synthesize) , do you have a different word to avoid setter and getter creation?

Comment: I agree with you about the use of undocumented api. Therefore if you don't want to use the image parameter with KeyValue approach, you have to create a custom object. simple as that. @NSManaged is for Core Data Object. Its side effect is that the getter performs valueForKey and the setter performs setValue:forKey:. This code is absolutely unsafe, and if the implementation of the image value changes in the future this will definitely lead to a crash. The short answer is "you should not do it anyway, as much as you should not use the private api"