# How to customise UIAlertAction?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uiactionsheet, uialertcontroller

Am using UIAlertController with UIAlertAction as buttons in it. I would like to add image to the button(UIAlertAction). Any help in this regard will be appreciable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26347085/add-image-to-uialertaction-in-uialertcontroller

Comment: Thank You Saurabh Prajapati. I have came across the same link before, but it didn't me help me out. That's why I posted again. Helping with some other solution will be appreciable. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can add an image/icon:

```swift
let action = UIAlertAction(...)
action.setValue(UIImage(named: "image-name", forKey: "image")
```