# How can i customize UIAlertAction in UIAlertController for iOS8?

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uialertcontroller

I need to add image in Action sheet item using `UIAlertController`. I add using:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
[alertAction setValue:image forKey:@"image"];
```

And results as:

[image: UIActionSheet]

The problem is that:
**I need the image & text to be centrally aligned and resize the height of Cancel button**

How can i do that, please share some code.

Thanks!

Comment: Create a custom nib file.

Comment: @CeceXX i had used it, it giving me error: `Assertion failure in -[UIAlertController viewWillAppear:]`

Comment: How did you find this key @"image"?

Comment: @BurhanuddinSunelwala means, i found from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26347085/add-image-to-uialertaction-in-uialertcontroller

Comment: @CeceXX you cannot create custom nib file for UIAlertAction! It is not a subclass of UIView. It is directly inherited from NSObject.

Comment: @BurhanuddinSunelwala You can. And this is an example: https://github.com/mattneub/custom-alert-view-iOS7.

Comment: @CeceXX they are making there own custom view controller and that is what I have explained in my answer. The custom alert view controller is not a subclass of UIAlertViewController. And we were talking about customizing UIAlertAction :)

Comment: Do you have a valid solution now? I met the same issue, and want to know how to solve the issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well, [here](https://github.com/JaviSoto/iOS8-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIAlertAction.h) is the Runtime Header file for `UIAlertAction`. You can neither change the frame of `image` nor you can change the height of `Cancel` button.

**So what is the solution?**

The only solution that I could figure is to make a custom view with UIVisualEffect and show/animate it like `UIActionSheet`. Basically you need to imitate `UIActionSheet`.

That said, I would like to welcome other solutions as well.