# How to add Tableview within UIActionSheet using Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to developing `popup view`, So I have decided If I develop `tableview menu within ActionSheet` , then its looking good for my `application` with `background blurry effects` also automatically will add by `UIActionSheet`. Please help me and post some code and ideas. Below I have give one example for what I am expecting

```
--------------------------------------------
|                                           |                   
|  Icon Title            checkmark          |
| ----------------------------------------- |
|                                           |                   
|  Icon Title            checkmark          |
| ----------------------------------------- |
|                                           |                   
|  Icon Title            checkmark          |
| ----------------------------------------- |
|                                           |                   
|  Icon Title            checkmark          |
--------------------------------------------
```

`Menu button` click to show above `action sheet` and `tableview` cell did select to hide.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29226050/how-can-i-customize-uialertaction-in-uialertcontroller-for-ios8

Comment: Thank you for share ur link. but there UIAlert customization, my questions is totaly different @Ajit

Comment: Well, you mentioned `UIActionSheet` & it is deprecated in iOS 8. To create and manage action sheets in iOS 8 and later, instead use `UIAlertController` with a preferredStyle of `UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet`.

Comment: Alright I understand. But give me some samples! Its not enough for me bcz i am new for iOS

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code to present action sheet with an image using [UIAlertController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/)

```
  UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController
      alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title"
                       message:@"message"
                preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

  UIAlertAction *tapAction = [UIAlertAction
      actionWithTitle:@"Title"
                style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
              handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
                  // add code to make something happen once tapped
              }];
  // add image & appears on left side.
  UIImage *accessoryImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
  [tapAction setValue:accessoryImage forKey:@"image"];

  [alertController addAction:tapAction];

  [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**Note:** here adding an image works in iOS 8 by using KVC (see [here](https://github.com/JaviSoto/iOS9-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIAlertAction.h)) ; property is not exposed. So, this may not be available in subsequent updates.

To customise it as per your need, I'd suggest you to build your own custom action sheet similar to UIActionSheet. Use a custom view/tableview and then, apply [UIVisualEffect](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIVisualEffect_class/index.html) plus animation.