# How to create UIAlertView with Image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uialertview

Hello everyone i have a question, if is possible to create UIAlertView with Image in Swift and how? If someone could help me because i don't find some example on network in swift practice all in objective c in iOS 6 not in iOS 7 or higher. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After iOS8 `UIAlertView` is deprecated so Apple recommends you to use `UIAlertController` instead of `UIAlertView`. And to accomplish what you asked you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26347085/add-image-to-uialertaction-in-uialertcontroller)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a workaround that I used successfully.

```
let myImage = UIImage(name:"myImage")
    let prevImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 50, width: 250, height: 172))
    prevImage.image = myImage
    let spacer = "\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n"
    let previewController = UIAlertController(title: "PREVIEW", message: spacer, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "SAVE", style: .Default) { (UIAlertAction) in
        self.uploadPatientPhoto(myImage!)
    }
    let retakeAction = UIAlertAction(title: "RETAKE", style: .Default) { (UIAlertAction) in
        self.retakeNewPatientPhoto(self)
    }
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "CANCEL", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
    previewController.addAction(saveAction)
    previewController.addAction(retakeAction)
    previewController.addAction(cancelAction)
    previewController.view.addSubview(prevImage)
    presentViewController(previewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: It's a shame that Apple didn't include a better way to add an image but this method breaks. From iOS8-iOS11. When the user has enabled larger text in their accessibility settings, the image interferes with the text.