# Action Sheet with Image for each option on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Is there any way to add an images to action sheet on iOS ? Same as apple do on there app store or apple musics app. My basic search on apple docs indicated that I don't subclass or add sub view in Action Sheet.

"UIActionSheet is not designed to be subclassed, nor should you add views to its hierarchy." -- Apple Docs

[image]

Answer (score 7):

To add an image in an action sheet you need to do something like this...

**Swift**

```
let image = UIImage(named: "myImageName")
let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Action 1", style: .default, handler: nil);
action.setValue(image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), forKey: "image")
```

**Objective C**

```
UIAlertAction* action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Action 1" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
[action setValue:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] forKey:@"image"];
```

Cheers :)

Comment: Problem with this kind of solution is, if let's suppose apple change the name of the method from setImage "image" to setImg above code will start crashing. I know we can guard using #selector but still not a safe option.

Comment: How about the alignment to left?

Answer (score 7):

Swift 4: If the image is larger and it doesn't fit well, use this code and UIImage Extension to resize the image:

```
func showAlert() {
    let alertController = UIAlertController()
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Title", style: .default) { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
    }
    if let icon = icon?.imageWithSize(scaledToSize: CGSize(width: 32, height: 32)) {
        action.setValue(icon, forKey: "image")
    }

    alertController.addAction(action)
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And use this extension:

```
extension UIImage {

    func imageWithSize(scaledToSize newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0)
        self.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height))
        let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return newImage
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

**In Swift**
       *It works only for UIAlertController Action Sheet*

```
        let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Action sheet style", message:"Action sheet with images", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        let action1 = addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Action1", style: .default, handler: nil))
        let image1 = UIImage(named: "Action1.png")
        action1.setValue(image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), forKey: "image")
        actionSheet.addAction(action1)
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

`UIActionSheet` is deprecated since iOS 8.3.
Use `UIAlertController` and its `UIAlertAction`s.
Take a look at [Add Image to UIAlertAction in UIAlertController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26347085/add-image-to-uialertaction-in-uialertcontroller)

Comment: Its a nice solution but its a hack.

Comment: Then, there is no solution other than custom controller with buttons styling the same way.

Answer (score 0):

`UIAlertController` has the same restriction that `UIActionSheet` had, there's no really good way to customize the layout.

You might want to check out libraries like [SDCAlertView](https://github.com/sberrevoets/SDCAlertView) that offer functional equivalents along with better customization options.

Comment: His solution works but doing something like this, looks wrong to me.         

var action = UIAlertAction(title: "Menu Item One", style: .default, handler: nil)
        action.setValue(image, forKey: "image")

Comment: I know and agree, and I'd never ship a hack like that.