# Xcode Swift how to add image to UIAlertController options?

Tags: swift, xcode, uialertcontroller

i want to add image/icon to `UIAlertController` like the dialog inside apple music player

what i want colored/sized image/icon like the image below, not like the one inside [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26347085/add-image-to-uialertaction-in-uialertcontroller) .i believe its ios 11+ feature but i can't find the documents for it .

**exactly like this :**

[image]

can i do this in `UIAlertController` or i should make my own custom dialog `uiviewcontroller`  ?

Comment: @the4kman its not duplicated i saw the question in ur link , is has tiny images , the one i want is colored images with same size :)

Comment: The answers address colorized images as well.

Comment: can you show me the colorized images inside the options in ur answer ?

Comment: @the4kman i will be waiting for ur answer of colored image in side the option in the link u've provided :) thanks

Comment: Hi, 
You can add multiple button in the alert 

You can check out this tutorial http://blog.ijasoneverett.com/2016/04/add-custom-uibutton-to-uialertcontroller/

Hope this helps

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)            
 alert.modalPresentationStyle = .popover


 let image = UIImage(named: "logoCircle")
 let imageView = UIImageView()
 imageView.image = image
 imageView.frame =  CGRect(x: 25, y: 18, width: 24, height: 24)
 alert.view.addSubview(imageView) 

 let image1 = UIImage(named: "icshare")
  let imageView1 = UIImageView()
  imageView1.image = image1
  alert.view.addSubview(imageView1)
  imageView1.frame = CGRect(x: 25, y: 75, width: 24, height: 24)

 let shareExternal = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Share External Link", comment: ""), style: .default) { action in
        }
 let shareInApp = UIAlertAction(title: "Share within", style: .default)   {
                action in
            } 

  alert.addAction(shareInApp)
  alert.addAction(shareExternal)


    if let presenter = alert.popoverPresentationController
    {
            presenter.sourceView = button
            presenter.sourceRect = button.bounds
    }
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: so the trick here i add the images in `UIAlertController` view !  its worked , but need make it on multi options just like the image above , +1 for the idea

Comment: @Jack . Check my updated answer

Comment: @UmaMadhavi Great answer! any idea why this causes layout constraint issues in Swift 5?