# Adding image in UIAlertAction from web url

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller, uiactionsheet, sdwebimage

[image]

Is there any way I can show an image from web url in my already shown UIAlertController's action. The real scenario is I've presented the UIAlertController and side by side I'm fetching the images from url. But now I wanted to update the UIAlertAction after image's are downloaded, but they aren't updating.

Later If i open the UIAlertController than those images get displayed in UIAlertAction.

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "My App", message: "Select option:", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        for url in arrUrl {
            let action = UIAlertAction(title: "url", style: .default) { (action) in

            }

            downloadImage(url) { (image) in
                if image != nil {
                    action.setValue(image, forKey: "image")
                }
            }
            alertController.addAction(action)
        }

func downloadImage(_ strUrl: String, completionHandler: @escaping(_ image: UIImage?) -> ()) {

        SDWebImageManager.shared().loadImage(
            with: URL(string: strUrl),
            options: .highPriority,
            progress: nil) { (image, data, error, cacheType, isFinished, imageUrl) in
                completionHandler(image)

        }
    }
```

Comment: Where did you get the source code from? There is no `image` property on the UIAlertAction object.

Comment: @SachinVas There is. We can add image in UIAlertController's action. See this link. https://medium.com/@maximbilan/ios-uialertcontroller-customization-5cfd88140db8

Comment: Looks like you are missing .withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal).

Comment: @SachinVas No that's not the case.

Comment: @RohitaxRajguru Perhaps it would be better if you create you'r own custom UIView with buttons/ImageViews, because using "setValue" function is a hack, so proper way is create your own.

Comment: @RohitaxRajguru.. check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47885322/5362916

Comment: It is not possible to update the alertAction once the alert controller is visible. You have to use as per the above stack overflow post.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done. You can extend the pattern used at the blog post you referenced (https://medium.com/@maximbilan/ios-uialertcontroller-customization-5cfd88140db8).

Instead of using a `UISwitch`, you can use a `UIImageView`. You can save the `UIViewController` that holds the `UIImageView` `IBOutlet` in your presenting view controller.

After fetching an image, you can update the `image` property of the `UIImageView`.

**Disclaimer:**

I'm pretty sure this `alertAction.setValue(..., forKey: "contentViewController")` business is an unsupported hack as the `contentViewController` property does not appear to be documented. So, although this may work today, it could break at any time. It could also get rejected when submitted to the AppStore.

**Use at your own risk**

Comment: If you check the blog for setting switch too they have used setValue function on alertAction.

Comment: Just because it’s mentioned in a blog post does not mean it’s officially supported. Apple’s UIAlertAction documentation makes no mention of this property. The fact that you have to use setValue, and there is no simple documented property, strongly suggests this is a private capability discovered through reverse engineering.