# How to add icons to options in action sheets : iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uialertcontroller

I am trying to add the icons in action sheet of iOS app. I saw that apple has implemented such behavior in AppStore's action sheet, but hasn't provided any callback method to implement it ?

Any suggestions on how to implement it on iOS 12 Swift 4.x Xcode10.x ??

[image: Action sheet with images.]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode Swift how to add image to UIAlertController options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47885042/xcode-swift-how-to-add-image-to-uialertcontroller-options)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Image to UIAlertAction in UIAlertController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26347085/add-image-to-uialertaction-in-uialertcontroller)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add image to `UIAlertAction` with `image` key:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "IMAGE_NAME")
var alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "TITLE", style: .default, handler: nil)
alertAction.setValue(image, forKey: "image")
```