# How to implement bottom menus in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, menu

How are these menus called in iOS and how to implement them in Objective-C ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called **UIAlertController**

Take a quick look at Apple's docs:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that with `UIAlertController` with image for every `UIAlertAction` . see more here [Alerts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26347085/add-image-to-uialertaction-in-uialertcontroller)